# Как заблокировать кликандер?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте установлен кликандер, который срабатывает при первом нажатии на любую область сайта. Можно ли как-то создать свой элемент и скрипт к нему, чтобы при нажатии на него не сработал кликандер, то есть заблокировать выполнение всех функций?

Answer (score 1):

Создаете элемент, на него вешаете событие onclick.

```
<div onclick={yourFunction(event)}>>test</div>
```

Создаете функцию

```
function yourFunction(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: То есть в таком случае, кликандер не сработает?

Comment: А `stopPropagation`? И зачем обработка события в html?  и еще имена функций не совпадают и вообще html блок не валидный...

Comment: @yolosora я не старался сделать html блок валидным, просто показал как это должно выглядеть. По поводу имен функций - спасибо, поправил.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Кликандер все равно срабатывает при клике.

Comment: @Eva_m попробуйте для созданного элемента использовать z-index  с большим значением. Есть вероятность что вы кликаете не на созданный элемент.

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин элемент имеет position: absolute + z-index:999999

Comment: @Eva_m можете прикрепить ваш код к вопросу?

Comment: Код чего именно? Он сделан по аналогии с вашим примером + скрипт партнерки.